# Копировать коллекцию полученную из ViewModel

Tags: android, viewmodel

В `activity` в методе `showList()` получаю элементы, коллекция `list` не пуста. Но когда копирую данные из нее в другую коллекцию, она оказывается пустой.

Вот сам метод

```
public class ShowActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private AppViewModel viewModel;
    private ItemsDao itemsDao;
    private ArrayList<Items> itemsList = new ArrayList<>();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_show);

        viewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(AppViewModel.class);
        itemsDao = AppDatabase.getInstance(this).itemsDao();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();

        showList();
    }

    private void showList() {
        viewModel.showItem(itemsDao);
        viewModel.getItems().observe(this, new Observer<PagedList<Items>>() {
            @Override
            public void onChanged(PagedList<Items> list) {
                Collections.copy(list, itemsList);
                System.out.println("list size " + list.size());
                System.out.println("itemsList size " + itemsList.size());
            }
        });

        FilterItems t = new FilterItems(mills1, mills2, 0);
        viewModel.filterItems.setValue(t);
    }

}
```

Метод `showList()` вызываю в `onResume()`. Как мне скопировать данные из нее в другую коллекцию?

Суть следующая: После копирования данных в другую коллекцию, из этой новой коллекции данные будут выводиться в диаграмму `AChartEngine`.

Comment: Добавьте, пожалуйста, сам код копирования и место использования скопированных данных.

Comment: обновил вопрос, класс выложил. в list есть данные, а в itemsList нет

Comment: Попробуйте сделать явное копирование вручную (в цикле по всем элементам list добавлять в itemsList). Это, по крайней мере, исключит возможность того, что Collections.copy работает неверно

Comment: попробую, спасибо.

Comment: 1) itemsDao = AppDatabase.getInstance(this).itemsDao(); - я правильно понимаю что тут вы получаете данные из БД в главном потоке?
2) В onChanged - точно приходит не пустой список?
3) Копируйте так - itemsList.addAll(list)

Comment: Да, все верно приходит не пустой список. По за пределами viewModel.getListCategoryForItemsForPeriod().observe список оказывается пустой (тот список куда я копировал из list)

Comment: observe выполняется асинхронно, то есть список может быть заполнен лишь спустя какое-то время, не используйте его (список), если использование происходит не внутри observe (использование может быть вынесено в отдельную функцию)

Comment: Можете привести пример как вы имеете ввиду?